# Cannot update attribute in xml file

Tags: python, xml

i want to ask something about update an attribute in xml file. i've created the codes but there's no errors. it's already read the parameter data, but its not post the updated value data.

my code :-

```
def user_submit(request):
    baseurl = request.build_absolute_uri()
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(baseurl)
    params = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
    param = params.get('Users', [''])[0]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsersForm(request.POST)

        passw = form.data['password']
        real = form.data['realname']

        # role = form.data['rolename']

        files = os.path.join(settings.WSS, 'users.xml')
        doc = minidom.parse(files)
        items = doc.getElementsByTagName("UserRepository")

        for items2 in items:
            for items3 in items2.getElementsByTagName("User"):

                username = items3.getAttribute('username')
                # items3 = []
                if username == param:
                    username = items3.getAttribute('username')
                    password = items3.getAttribute('password')
                    realname = items3.getAttribute('realname')


                    items3.attributes['password'].value = passw
                    items3.attributes['realname'].value = real


                # for items4 in items3.getElementsByTagName("Role"):
                #     results2.append({
                #        items4.attributes['rolename'].value = role })

        xml_file = open(files, "w")
        doc.writexml(xml_file, encoding="utf-8")
        xml_file.close()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse( 'users_list'))
```

param value:-

[parameter's value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTCdi.jpg)

anyone can help me to solve this problem. ﻿